# Django ORM Cannot filter by reversed foreign key

Tags: django, apache, django-models, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have a weird behaviour on my production server. When I try to filter by reversed foreign key then I receive an error that it is not possible, but locally it works fine, e.g.:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    foo = models.ForeignKey('Foo', related_name='bars', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

Now trying to do:

```
Foo.objects.filter(bars__name=xyz)
```

will result with

Cannot resolve keyword 'bars' into field. Choices are: ...

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and django 1.8.7

**EDIT 1:**
can it be related to the fact that ForeignKeys are defined using string representation?

**EDIT 2:**
I have found relation which is defined using class not string, so it doesn't work for such relations as well.

Basically model `Foo` has many `ForeignKey` relations. Few in `Foo`, few in target models. These in target models do not exist on production when running query from `Foo` perspective. These in `Foo` can be used as query params.

**EDIT 3:**
I have received more detailed information of server configuration and when exactly error occurs.

Info about the production setup where the issue is seen:

- apache version: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.3
- libapache2-mod-wsgi version: 4.3.0-1.1build1

Apache mpm_event config:

```
StartServers 2
MinSpareThreads 25
MaxSpareThreads 75
ThreadLimit 64
ThreadsPerChild 25
MaxRequestWorkers 150
MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
```

Relevant part of apache site config:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess some_name group=some_name maximum-requests=1000 processes=2 threads=15 user=some_name
WSGIProcessGroup some_name
WSGIScriptAlias / "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/some_name/wsgi.py"
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Basically error does not happen with every request. When it appears then it comes from one worker. Restarting apache fixes errors for some time.

One of the thoughts is that there may be a race condition in loading django models.

Comment: The `fk` should be on `Foo` and the related name `bars`

Comment: It should work both ways. Withouth related_name the query should be filter(bar_set__name=xyz)

Comment: What is more locally everything seems to be fine.

Comment: But what model is 'bars'?

Comment: sorry, corrected code

Comment: Yup, don't pass it as a string.

Comment: You could try using `through`.

Comment: Please show the actual models, query and error. Your example with `Foo` and `Bar` looks ok.

Comment: @Alasdair I have added more detailed information about production server configuration, as it may be the place I should look for solution.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the `fk` properly:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    pass

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, related_name='bars', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

To deal with circular imports:

```
foo = models.ForeignKey('<app_name>.Foo', related_name='bars', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

Comment: oh yes you are right, I have made mistake in pseudocode. now corrected.

Comment: Cool =) Pass `Foo` directly rather than as string.

Comment: There is a problem, that we have lots of model and there are circular imports

Comment: Can you import it so: `class Bar(models.Model): 
from <app.models> import Foo`?

Comment: Thx for advice, I will try.

Comment: added some updates, unfortunately with class instead of string it does not work as well.

Comment: @szaman Sorry it didn't help, I will have a look again as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Yes that is what we are using. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

You must use [related_query_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) in your query filter. By default in Django 1.8 it's model name, so set custom related_query_name or change your code to this:

```
Foo.objects.filter(bar__name=xyz)
```

Comment: from docs: The name to use for the reverse filter name from the target model. It defaults to the value of related_name or default_related_name if set, otherwise it defaults to the name of the model.

Comment: So it should work with related_name defined, but worth trying.

Comment: @Dima Kudosh `related_name` definitely works. It is what I use in my code all the time and never run into an issue.

Comment: It defaults to the value of related_name or default_related_name if set, otherwise it defaults to the name of the model for latest Django. In django 1.8 it's default to model name. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name